# Gulp.js - Rewrite urls embedded in css while concatenating

Tags: javascript, css, gulp

I'm using Gulp to concatenate several css files from different directories (Bower managed dependencies). Font-awesome is one of these dependencies and it contains a relative reference to its fonts `url(../font....)`. When the css file is concatenated and placed in a different directory this relative url will obviously be wrong. Is there a best practice for dealing with this?

Comment: Sounds like a job for [`gulp-replace`](https://github.com/lazd/gulp-replace).

Comment: Thanks, that did the job for me. Should have figured something like that existed. Mind writing that as an answer so I can accept it? Thanks!

Comment: Could you pls explain how you solved it with gulp.replace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is gulp-css-rebase-urls which was built to address this problem.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-css-rebase-urls

Comment: This would be extremely useful, but unfortunately it looks like this project is no longer supported.  Are there any active alternatives?

Answer (score 7):

You can use gulp-replace.
https://npmjs.org/package/gulp-replace

```
**gulp-replace can be called with a string or regex.**

*replace(string, replacement)*

string

Type: String

The string to search for replacement

Type: String

The replacement string.

*replace(regex, replace)*

Note: gulp-replace cannot perform regex replacement on streams.

regex

Type: RegExp
```

You could also use gulp-frep

Comment: Just noticed @robertklep answer in the comments.