# How to rewrite relative paths of fonts and images in CSS-files (Gulp.js)?

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp

At the build of project's front-end with Gulp.js, CSS-files from **bower_components** refer to their images and fonts with relative path - how to rewrite to absolute paths?

For example, input file with some content:

```
.info{
    background: url(themes/assets/hello.png)
}
```

Output file:

```
.info{
    background: url(/static/img/hello.png)
}
```

Also, URLs that refer to some CDN not changed.

How to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21529979/gulp-js-rewrite-urls-embedded-in-css-while-concatenating ?